# Getting an "mkdir(): Permission Denied" error

Tags: ubuntu

I installed the Gantry 5 framework no problem into Joomla! (using "Upload Package File"), then I tried to install the theme for it and I received this error:

> '/opt/bitnami/apps/joomla/htdocs/templates/g5_hydrogen/custom/config/default' failed on error mkdir(): Permission denied

Clearly it is some sort of permission issue.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `sudo` word before your command line.

ie `sudo chmod 777 <path>`

Answer (score 1):

Check out the user and group you are running you  WebServer. 
Then  you should change user and  group owner:

```
chown user:group  /opt/bitnami/apps/joomla/htdocs/templates/g5_hydrogen/custom/
```

Answer (score 0):

The user that you are trying to make the directory with either does not have permissions to make a directory in that location, or you simply need to add the word `sudo` before the command.

Try adding `sudo` first and see what the response is. Either the directory will be created as you want, or you do not have `sudo` permissions meaning that you need to login as someone with `sudo` permissions and make the directory.

However, once you have logged in as a user that does have the permissions required to make a directory there you could change the permissions of the file path so that the original user you tried could make a directory there, which can be accomplished using the `chmod` command.